# Can Darboux Theorem be stronger by making the derivative at c continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity

Darboux Theorem: If $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $\eta$ between $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$, then exists $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f'(c)=\eta$.

The common counterexample about $f'$ at $c$ not necessarily continuous is $f(x)=x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}(\mathbb{R}-\{0\}); 0(0)$, $\eta=0$ and $f'(0)=0$ where $f'$ is not continuous. Yet we have a lot of zeroes around the point $0$ and all of $f'$ there are continuous.

It's easy to prove there are these discontinuities of $f'$ are convergence points (Edit: This proof is wrong.), but the points around could also be discontinuities. I want to state that we can find this $c$ such that $f'$ is continuous at $c$, which is a stronger proposition.

Is this statement true? If so, how to prove it, and can we extend it to "continuous on its neighborhood"? If not, do we have a counterexample?

Comment: Martin R yes. I've edited the question.

Comment: A derivative is a Baire 1 function: it can not be so badely discontinuous.

Comment: For those who might be interested, the Darboux property of derivatives has been  increasingly strengthened by others: First strengthened independently by Denjoy (1916) and [Clarkson (1947)](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1947-53-02/S0002-9904-1947-08757-7/), then further strengthened by [Zahorski (1950)](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1950-069-00/S0002-9947-1950-0037338-9/), then even further strengthened by [Weil (1973)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24890649), then still even further strengthened by [Bullen/Sarkhel (1996)](https://doi.org/10.4153/CMB-1996-002-6). **(continued)**

Comment: For more details and some related issues, see [this 21 May 2008 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/Pk_pWyP-8Pc/m/YcnSAIVzTbwJ).

Comment: OH NO. My "proof" about the infinite amount of zeroes around c is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a better counter-example such that only one such $c$ exists, at which $f'$ is discontinuous. Define the triangular function $h_n$ such that $h_n(2^{-n})=1$, and $h_n(2^{-n} - 2^{-2(n+2)}) = h_n(2^{-n} + 2^{-2(n+2)}) = 0$. Then $\int h_n = 2^{-2(n+2)}$, and defining $H(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} h_n(x)$, we have that $H$ is continuous on $(0,+\infty)$ and has no limit in $0$.

Now define $F(x) = \int_0^x H(t) dt$ for $x>0$. We have that $F$ is non-decreasing and $F(2^{-n}) \leq \sum_{k=n}^{+\infty} 2^{-2(k+2)} \leq \left(2^{-(n+1)}\right)^2$, and so $F(x) \leq x^2$. Mirroring the same arguments on $(-\infty,0)$, we can define $F(x)$ on all $\mathbb{R}$ so that $F$ is even.

We're almost done. To make sure that $f'$ equals $0$ only at $x=0$, we can just define $f(x) = x^2 + F(x)$ for example, thus $0 \leq \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} \leq 2x \underset{x\to0}{\longrightarrow} 0$. We now have $f$ such that $f'(x)>0$ for $x>0$, $f'(x)<0$ for $x<0$, $f'(0) = 0$, and $f'$ is discontinuous at $0$.

This counter-example shows that for all $\alpha<\eta<\beta$, we can choose a function $f$ such that $f'(a)=\alpha$, $f'(b)=\beta$, and $f'$ is discontinuous at all the points where $f'(c)=\eta$. To me, the next step would be to find whether there can exist a single $f$ such that this stays true for all $\eta\in(\alpha,\beta)$. Based on the comments I presume it's not possible, but it'd be interesting to see what happens if we restrict how large the subset of valid $\eta$'s must be (e.g. almost every $\eta\in(\alpha,\beta)$, or even just a countably infinite subset).